# Strtok usage, code not working

Tags: c, strtok

I am trying to use `strtok()`. Following is the piece of code that I wrote. It does not work but prints `",  '"` infinitely.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
char str[]="this, by the way, is a 'sample'";
char *tokens;
tokens = strtok(str, ", '");
//printf("%s\n",tokens);
//printf("%s\n", str);
while(tokens!=NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", tokens);
    tokens = (NULL, ", '");
}
return 0;
}
```

Following is the code from a `strtok()` manual page, which works perfectly fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I feel I have done the exact same thing. Can't figure out the fault in my code. Could someone please point out.

Comment: The duplicate marked this question is complete wrong! in this question OP forgot name of function in codding and because of `,` comma operator's behavior no error generated While linked question is about the behavior of  operator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Interesting bug! You forgot function name. Notice inside while-loop body following expression:

```
tokens =  (NULL, ",'");
         ^ 
          'strtok' missing
```

should be:

```
tokens = strtok(NULL, ",'");
```

Interesting thing is that this is **not a compilation error**, in fact:

```
tokens = (NULL, ",'");
```

is a valid expression which is equals to:

```
tokens = ",'";
```

(Note: `NULL` has no side effects)

Read: [Comma Operator: `,`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs06xbxh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> The comma operator `,` has `left-to-right associativity`. Two expressions
>   separated by a comma are evaluated left to right. The left operand is
>   always evaluated, and all side effects are completed before the `right
>   operand is evaluated`.

Due to  parenthesis `(` `)` at rhs of `=`, after evaluating `,` operator right hand operand `","`  is assigned to `token`.  And because `token` never assigned `NULL` so `while(tokens != NULL)` never breaks, and this is the reason that you are getting `","` infinitely!

Comment: thanks bro, galti se mistake ho gaya. :). samajh nahi aa raha tha kya galti hai, so i posted

Comment: @naka no problem, your welcome!.. its obvious mistake :) -- important is to understand why it compiled

Comment: `/*missing calleable-expr*/(expr..., exprn)` -- behold, the _"`coma-operator`"_. Note that the result may not evaluate to `exprn` in the presence of overloaded `operator,`

Comment: @sehe yes Sehe that is a point but Question is tagged to [tag:C]

Comment: Good point. Too bad it kinda spoils a good joke :( Oh well