# What is the name of this syntax "(x, y)"?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I recently read a javascript code and I came across this line:

```
var myVar = (12,5); // myVar==5 now
```

What is this *strange* syntax : `(x, y)` ?

Comment: [Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [**Comma Operator: `,`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)
>
> The comma operator `,` has `left-to-right associativity`. Two expressions
>   separated by a comma are evaluated left to right. The left operand is
>   always evaluated, and all side effects are completed before the right
>   operand is evaluated.

The expression:

```
var myVar = (12, 5);
```

is equivalent to:

```
var myVar = 5;
```

Note, in above expression parenthesis overwrites precedence of `,` over `=`, otherwise without parenthesis an expression  like `var myVar = 12, 5` is equivalent to var `myVar = 12`.
**Edit:** There can be following reasons I guess that you find this expression:

1. **When first expression has some side-effects:**

   ```
    var myVar = ( expression1, expression2);
   ```

   The `expression1` may have some side effects that may required before to assign the result of `expression2`  to `myVar`, e.g.  `var mayVar = (++i, i + j);`  In this expression incremented value after `++i` will be added with `j` and result will be assigned to `mayVar`.
2. **Bug fixed or bug:**
   May be some bug fixing/or during testing instead of assigning `x` developer wanted to assign `y` but *forgot* to remove `(` `)` before public relies.

   ```
   var myVar = (x, y);
   ```

   I also find a typo-bug in which questioner forgot to write function same and instead of writing

   ```
   var myVar = fun(x, y);
   ```

   his typo:

   ```
   var myVar = (x, y);
   ```

   In the linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896507/strtok-usage-code-not-working?answertab=votes#tab-top).

This is not JavaScript link but very interesting C++ link where  legitimate/or possible use of comma operators was discussed [What is the proper use of the comma operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902992/what-is-the-proper-use-of-the-comma-operator?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

it is called Comma Operator, we usually use them when we want to run 2 statement in one single expression, it evaluates 2 operands (left-to-right) and returns the value of the second one.

check it here: [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

And read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579546/comma-operator-where-it-can-really-be-useful) if you want to know where it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is called the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).

The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the second operand.

Here are some examples:

```
 var a = (12,3) //a =3;
 var b = (a+2, 2) //a=5, b= 2
 var c = (a,b) // a= 5, b=2, c=2.
```